# How to create a query in the entity repository with a many-to-many relationship? Empty query

Tags: symfony, dql

I have got a many-to-many relationship between advert and document : here are the 3 tables :

advert
document
document_advert.

How can I get the `author` from Advert and the `path` from Document? 
The first attempt does not throw any error, but the query seems empty, I don't understand this from the debugger :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

My goal is something like this in sql :

```
SELECT d.path, a.author 
FROM document_advert da 
JOIN document d 
JOIN advert a 
WHERE da.advert_id = 1 
AND da.document_id = d.id
```

My attempt (I am in the AdvertRepository) :

```
public function getDocNames($id){
     $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->join('a.document', 'd')
            ->addSelect('d')
            ->where("a.id = :id")
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
    ;
    return $query->getResult();
    //issue: empty query

}
```

---

EDIT : I am trying to get all the values from `d`, without calling them explicitly (I don't want to do `d.path, d.name, etc.` but `d` instead). But ".path" in the twig file is not recognized if I don't add "d.path" in the query.

in twig:

```
{% for doc in docNames %}
    {{ doc.path }}
{% endfor %}
```

If I remove `.path` in the query, ".path" "does not exist " : here is the query in the DQL format :

```
public function getDocNamesC($id){
        $query = $this->_em->createQuery("SELECT a, d.path FROM OCPlatformBundle:Advert a JOIN a.documents d WHERE a.id = $id");
        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: Your querybuilder looks OK, though you would need to call getResult() as well to get results. Can you post your many to many relations from document and advert entities?

Comment: @Richard I edited my post. If by any chance you can also tell me the problem how to write the query in DQL it would be great.

Comment: You've forgotten to include a `->from('advert', 'a')` in your query.

Comment: @sketchthat thanks, I am in the AdvertRepository, so "a" in the createQueryBuilder should know it stands for Advert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you defined the `$em` variable and didn't use it. I assume you were trying to do something like the below.

```
public function getDocNames($id){
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    return $qb->select('a.author')
        ->addSelect('d.path')
        ->from('OCPlatformBundle:Advert', 'a')
        ->join('a.documents', 'd')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->eq('a.id', ':id')
        )
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

If you want to get the full entities

```
public function getDocNames($id){
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    return $qb->select('a')
        ->addSelect('d')
        ->from('OCPlatformBundle:Advert', 'a')
        ->join('a.documents', 'd')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->eq('a.id', ':id')
        )
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Then when accessing the result in Twig

```
{% for advert in docNames %}
    {{ advert.name }}

    {% for document in advert.documents %}
       {{ document.path }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

We need to loop through the documents because it's a `many-to-many` relationship so there isn't one `path` per `advert`.

Comment: Thanks, because I am in the AdvertRepository, I used "a" as an alias, and tried both ways with $em and $this. I tried your function but it says "unknown namespace OC", but I did not change anything, the namespace works everywhere else with OC.

Comment: Try OCPlatformBundle:Advert (or just the full namespace\entity will work too) and the join to a.document should be a.documents

Comment: @Richard and sketchthat thanks, with "documents" it worked fine, I was already in the AdvertRepository so I didn't need to add the from statement, just in case someone is in the same situation. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hi @sketchthat , I would have another question : `.path` in my view is not recognized if I don't explicitly call `d.path` in the query, would you know why? How to get all the values from `d` ? I edited my post.